# How do i pass variables from class to a new class?

Tags: c#

I have this class wich I will make an instance for it in Form1 later that pass variables from Form1 to the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    class WebcrawlerConfiguration
    {

        public string url;
        public int levels;
        public string mainurl;
        public Dictionary<string,List<string>> localy;
        public bool removeext;
        public bool downloadcontent;
        public int failedUrls;
        public bool toCancel;
        public System.Threading.ManualResetEvent busy;

        public WebcrawlerConfiguration()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How do I make that this class will get the variables from Form1 ?
Each variable in the class should get the variable in Form1 when I will make an instance for the class.

Then I have this class:

```
class BackgroundWebCrawling
    {
        int counter = 0;
        List<string> WebSitesToCrawl;
        BackgroundWorker mainBackGroundWorker;
        BackgroundWorker secondryBackGroundWorker;
        WebCrawler webcrawler1;
        WebcrawlerConfiguration webcrawlerCFG;
        public BackgroundWebCrawling()
        {
            mainBackGroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            mainBackGroundWorker.DoWork += mainBackGroundWorker_DoWork;
        }

        private void mainBackGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < WebSitesToCrawl.Count; i++)
            {
                if (counter >= 3)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                else
                {
                    webcrawler1 = new WebCrawler(webcrawlerCFG);
                    counter++;
                    secondryBackGroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                    secondryBackGroundWorker.DoWork += secondryBackGroundWorker_DoWork;
                }


            }            
        }

        private void secondryBackGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

                if (offlineOnline == true)
                {
                    offlinecrawling(f, levelsToCrawl, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    webcrawler1.webCrawler(
                }
                counter--;
        }
```

In the bottom here im doing: webcrawler1.webCrawler(
The function webCralwer should get all the variables from the first class WebcrawlerConfiguration.

This is how the WebCrawler function looks like:

```
public List<string> offlinecrawling(string url, int levels, string mainurl, Dictionary<string, List<string>> localy, bool removeext, bool downloadcontent, int failedUrls, bool toCancel, System.Threading.ManualResetEvent busy)
```

So now when im doing webcrawler1.webCrawler( 
It's asking for all the variables...But I want to pass them somehow from the WebcrawlerConfiguration.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Just change the signature to accept a `WebCrawlerConfiguration` instance e.g. `public List<string> offlinecrawling(WebcrawlerConfiguration config)` then in the method, copy the values out of the passed in object

Comment: Thanks Charleh. Working.